$\pi$ phase shift upon reflection in quantum wells
Is there a similar phenomenon to the $\pi$ phase shift experienced by light upon reflection from a medium of lower to higher refracted index for particles in different potentials?
For instance, does a particle experience a $\pi$ shift when reflected at a potential step or, conversely from a potential well?
